# Dynamically wrapping a random number React components at run time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have say the following simple components:

```
const CompOne = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="compOne">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const CompTwo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="compTwo">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const CompThree = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="compThree">
      {props.content}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now during run time, after making an AJAX request the client receives information that gives the order in which components need to wrap into one another. The result of that AJAX request would look something like this:

```
let renderMap = [
  { component: CompOne, props: {} },
  { component: CompTwo, props: {} },
  { component: CompThree, props: { content: "hi there" } }
];
```

So the composition should flow by iterating through the array and composing one component into the next. e.g: CompOne(CompTwo(CompThree)))

Two important things to note when I tried creating a wrapping HOC to fix this issue:

**Edit: Important detail I forgot to mention in the original post**

1) The number of components to wrap **will not be consistent**. At times it could be 3, but other times as many as 4, 5, 6 components needed to wrap into each other

2) The order could be different each time

```
<CompOne>
  <CompTwo>
    <CompThree content="hi there">
    </CompThree>
  </CompTwo>
</CompOne>
```

So my resulting HTML would be:

```
<div className="compOne">
  <div className="compTwo">
    <div className="compThree">
      hi there
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried various things but I can't get it to work once I start getting past just wrapping two components. Is this something I can even do in React?

Comment: "I can't get it to work once I start getting past just wrapping two components". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Will the order of the components will be received from Ajax response too? If so what does it look like? [Here is](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) an idea if it help.

Comment: Just a clarification. Can you confirm that when you get the Ajax response.. you have 1) all the information you need about which components should be used, 2) all the information you need about which order of layering they should have.

Comment: Updated the post with the AJAX response. Order does come in and it's simply an array you iterate through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the link that  [Arup Rakshit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) posted in the comments showed, you can use components that are stored in a variable - with JSX - as long as they are capitalized:

```
// in render()
const MyComp = props.someVariableContainingAComponent;
return <MyComp />;
```

With that in mind, one approach to your problem would be to iterate through all your components, starting with inner one, and then taking the each of the next to use as a wrapper for the previous one. Given the shape of your test data `renderMap`, and using `Array.protype.reduce` for the iteration, it could look something like this:

```
renderComponents(renderMap) {
  const Component = renderMap
   .reverse()
   .reduce( (ComponentSoFar, {component, props}) => {
     const Outer = component;
     return () => (<Outer {...props} ><ComponentSoFar /></Outer>);
   }, props => null ); // initial value, just a "blank" component
 return ( <Component /> );
}
```

I have included a demo showing how both different number of components and varying order of nesting can be handled with this approach.

```js
const CompOne = (props) => (
    <div className="comp compOne"><p>One:</p>{ props.content || props.children } </div>);
const CompTwo = (props) => (
 <div className="comp compTwo"><p>Two:</p> { props.content || props.children }</div>);
const CompThree = (props) => (
 <div className="comp compThree"><p>Three:</p> { props.content || props.children }</div>);
const CompFour = (props) => (
 <div className="comp compFour"><p>Four:</p> { props.content || props.children }</div>);
const CompFive = (props) => (
 <div className="comp compFive"><p>Five:</p> { props.content || props.children }</div>);

const renderMap1 = [
  { component: CompOne, props: {} },
  { component: CompTwo, props: {} },
  { component: CompThree, props: {} },
  { component: CompFour, props: {} },
  { component: CompFive, props: { content: "hi there" } }
];
const renderMap2 = [].concat(renderMap1.slice(1,4).reverse(), renderMap1.slice(4))
const renderMap3 = renderMap2.slice(1);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  renderComponents(renderMap) {
     const Component = renderMap
      .reverse()
      .reduce( (ComponentSoFar, {component, props}) => {
        const Outer = component;
        return () => (<Outer {...props} ><ComponentSoFar /></Outer>);
      }, props => null ); // initial value, just a "blank" component
    return ( <Component /> );
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( <div> 
      { this.renderComponents(renderMap1) } 
      { this.renderComponents(renderMap2) } 
      { this.renderComponents(renderMap3) } 
    </div> );
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.comp {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.compOne { border-color: red;}
.compTwo { border-color: green;}
.compThree { border-color: blue;}
.compFour { border-color: black;}
.compFive { border-color: teal;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: New info was added to the question. Given that info, this approach doesn't work.

You can probably solve it using a [Higher-order component (HOC)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html), something like this:

```
const superWrapped = (Outer) => (Middle) => (Inner) => props => {
   return (
    <Outer>
      <Middle>
        <Inner content={props.content} />
      </Middle>
    </Outer>
   )
 };
```

Where you would later use it like this:

```
render() {
  const SuperWrapped = 
    superWrapped(CompOne)(CompThree)(CompTwo); // any order is fine!
  return (<SuperWrapped content="Something here.." /> );
}
```

Some minor adjustments on your components would be necessary for this to work. I've included a working demo below:

```js
const superWrapped = (Outer) => (Middle) => (Inner) => props => {
 return (
    <Outer>
      <Middle>
        <Inner content={props.content} />
      </Middle>
    </Outer>)
};

const CompOne = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="compOne">
      <p>One:</p>
      {props.children || props.content}
    </div>
  );
};

const CompTwo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="compTwo">
      <p>Two:</p>
      {props.children || props.content}
    </div>
  );
};

const CompThree = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="compThree">
      <p>Three:</p>
      {props.children || props.content}
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
   const components = getComponentOrder();
      
    const SuperWrapped1 = 
     superWrapped(components[0])(components[1])(components[2]);
    const SuperWrapped2 = 
     superWrapped(components[2])(components[1])(components[0]);
    return (
    <div>
      <SuperWrapped1 content="Hello, world!" />
      <SuperWrapped2 content="Goodbye, world!" />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

const getComponentOrder = () => {
 return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 
     [CompOne, CompTwo, CompThree] :
      Math.random() < 0.5 ?  
       [CompThree, CompOne, CompTwo] :
        [CompTwo, CompOne, CompThree]
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.compOne {
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.compTwo {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.compThree {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now, I had something similar to this with a wrapping HOC. But in your example, what if we didn't know how many components we would have to wrap? Is there a way to still make this work then because that's another issue I will be facing. Sometimes we could be wrapping 3 Components into each other but others times more

Comment: I see. That's **very** important information which wasn't mentioned. The question only mentioned that the *order* was unknown until runtime. I see you edited your question now, but please use something like **Edit: The new info here), or else my answer won't make sense to future readers (and I risk down-votes). This answer is not flexible enough for an unknown number of components, no. I think another approach is needed.

Comment: You're right, I updated the post and apologize for that. Totally my fault.

Comment: No problem. I needed to practice using HOC's anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a recursive function:

```js
let renderMap = [
  { component: CompOne, props: {} },
  { component: CompTwo, props: {} },
  { component: CompThree, props: { content: "hi there" } }
];

function App() {
  
  let index = 0;

  let structure = "Hi There!"
  
  function packing() {
    if (index === renderMap?.length) return;

    const Comp = renderMap[index].component

    structure = <Comp>{structure}</Comp>;

    index += 1;

    packing();
  }

  packing();

  return <>{structure}</>
}
```